# Opening a new dialog box whenever an option is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I open a new dialog box whenever a user clicks on an option in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say a "new" dialog?

Then you'll need to destroy the current dialog and then recreate it.

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $(this).dialog(optionsToCreate); //create the dialog on click with your options
    $(this).dialog("open"); //then open it
});
```

We'll then destroy the dialog when it's closed.

```
$("li").bind("dialogclose", function(event, ui){
    $(this).dialog("destroy");
});
```

Edit for your comment...

to create the dialog for each option
put this in your page load...

```
$(function(){ //page load function
    $("li").dialog();
});
```

Then to bind to the click handler to open the dialog

```
$("li").dialog("open");
```

Would need to see some of your code to see what the HTML looks like or you'll need to revise your question to include some detail. But opening dialogs is pretty straight forward and the default options allow for "stacking" you may have to play with the position options if you want them to be visible in a certain layout.

Comment: I mean the old dialog should also be present along with the new one, i,e., a dialog for every click to options

Comment: When i do like that, list items are not getting displayed, instead a dialog box is created for every list item.

Comment: A separate dialog box is created when the list item is clicked but the clicked list item is getting disappeared, Why is it so. I dont need any list item to disappear when clicked.

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing any of your code. Like William, I suggest you do some reading on jQuery and javascript. If you're still having problems open a new question and include some detail. Your original question was only a sentence long. It's tough for us to help under these circumstances

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".yourClass li").click(function(){
     $(this).dialog();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to create a new dialog each time, you can do something like this:

```
$('li').click( function() {
    // attach a dialog for each list item
    if(!$(this).data('dialog')) {
        var dialog = $('<div>').html($(this).html()).dialog({ autoOpen:false });
        $(this).data('dialog', dialog);
    }

    // open the attached dialog for that item
    $(this).data('dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/5pwVN/2/

**EDIT**:

You can cache the settings and open a different dialog each time with the same settings:

```
var dialogSettings = {
    draggable: true,
    modal: false,
    title: 'Chat Area',
    buttons: {
        "Add": function() {
            $('#add-to-chat').dialog('open');
        },
        "Send File": function() {
            $('#send-file').dialog('open');
        },
        "End": function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
};

$('.roster-contact').live('click', function () {
    $('<div>').html('some chats').dialog(dialogSettings);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/5pwVN/3/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, its working. But i have to open the dialog box which i have created already. In my application i have already created a dialog with the name 'chat-area' which has to be opened

Comment: .....    $('#chat-area').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true,
        modal: false,
        title: 'Chat Area',
        buttons: {
         "Add": function(){
          $('#add-to-chat').dialog('open');
         },
         "Send File": function(){
          $('#send-file').dialog('open');
         },
            "End": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
........ $('.roster-contact').live('click', function () {

Comment: Its a part of chat application which connects to the Jabber server to fetch users information. When an user is clicked, a new chat dialog should be opened. Thats the requirement

Comment: Will the above code suffice for your analysis? Can u pls help me in this matter

Comment: Do you mean you want to open a "new" dialog with the same style as one (i.e. `#chat-area`) that you created?

Comment: Exactly that's my requirement

Comment: Its working fine, but how can i refer the dialog that is opened? Means i need to add some more features dynamically to the dialog. In order to do that i need to refer the dialog by a name. How can i do that. dont mind disturbing u

Comment: You simply assign each dialog to a variable or attach it to an element, like my first example.

Comment: One more doubt, pls dont mind, i need to refer the created dialog with '#chat-area' dialog because all the features added dynamically are referred to '#chat-area' dialog. How can i do that?

Comment: you should post another question... I already answered your question, if not more.

Comment: Hi, as u said i can store the result of $('<div>').html('').dialog(dialogSettings);  in a variable, but my doubt is instead of having it as a variable, i need it as a dialog object some thing like $('#chat-area'). I may be disturbing u, but i am not able to convert that variable to a dialog

Comment: My friend, it became pretty clear that you are lacking some fundamental knowledge of jQuery and, perhaps, JavaScript. I strongly encourage you to spend some time on a tutorial or two on jQuery, e.g. http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works and http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/jQueryPluginTutorial_Beginner.

Comment: Ok sure, actually i am new to JQuery, i havent used it before